# How to access to eventHandler functions from a React Component?

Tags: reactjs

I have the following scenario and I don't know how to access to EventHandler functions in SearchComponent.

The issue is that I'm not able to read values from

```
let transportItems = EventHandlers.getTransportModeItems; 
// If use EventHandlers.getTransportModeItems() 
// I get a message that says React is undefined
```

in SearchComponent.

SearchComponent.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import BaseSearchComponent from './baseSearch/baseSearch'
import EventHandlers from './helpers/eventHandlers'

export default class SearchComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            transportChoices: {
                from: '',
                to: ''  
            },
            error: {
                from: '',
                to: ''
            }
        };
    }

    render() {
        let fromClass = this.state.error.from ? 'has-error': '';
        let toClass = this.state.error.to ? 'has-error': '';
        let transportItems = EventHandlers.getTransportModeItems; // If use EventHandlers.getTransportModeItems() I get a message that says React is undefined

        console.log(transportItems);

        return (
            <div className="container search-container">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-12">
                        <form action="/search" method="GET">
                            <DefaultSearchComponent fromClass={fromClass} toClass={toClass}
                                transportModeItems={transportItems} 
                openModeDropdown={EventHandlers.openModeDropdown}
                state={this.state}  />

                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

baseSearchComponent.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Autocomplete from 'react-google-autocomplete';

export default class BaseSearchComponent extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
        <div className="form-container">
            <div className="white-container">
                <div className={'from-col ' + this.props.fromClass}>
                    <div className="autocomplete-container">
                        <label className="lbl-from" htmlFor="from">FROM:</label>
                        <Autocomplete id="from" name="from" className="from-field"
                        types={[]} componentRestrictions={{country: "us"}} />
                  </div>
                    <div className="from-input-error">{this.props.state.error.from}</div>
                </div>
                <div className={'to-col ' + this.props.toClass}>
                    <div className="autocomplete-container">
                        <label className="lbl-to" htmlFor="to">TO:</label>
                        <Autocomplete id="to" name="to" className="to-field"
                        types={[]} componentRestrictions={{country: "us"}} />
                    </div>
                    <div className="to-input-error">{this.props.state.error.to}</div>
                </div>
                <div className="mode-col">
                    <div className="transport-mode-container" onClick={this.props.openModeDropdown} >
                        <label className="lbl-type">Mode</label>
                        <img src={this.props.state.transportChoices.mode_icon} id="img_mode_selected" />
                        <input type="text" className="transport-mode-value" disabled="true"
                        name="transportMode" id="input_mode_selected" value={this.props.state.transportChoices.mode} />
                    </div>
                    <ul className={'transport-mode-dropdown ' + this.props.dropdownModeVisible} >
                        {this.props.transportModeItems}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
   );
    }
}
```

and eventHandlers.jsx

```
import constants from '../shared/util/constants.json';

let eventHandlers = {
  getTransportModeItems: function() {
    console.log("function triggered");
    // component.props.actions.updateNavigator('basalRate')
    const transportModes = constants.transport_modes
    let transportOptions = []
    for (var k = 0; k < transportModes.length; k++) {
        transportOptions.push(<li key={k}
        onClick={this.handleSelectMode.bind(this, transportModes[k])}>
        {transportModes[k].label} <img src={transportModes[k].icon} /></li>)
    }
    return transportOptions;
  }


  openModeDropdown() {
    this.setState({displayMode: !this.state.displayMode})
  }

};

export default eventHandlers;
```

Also I'm not able to access openModeDropdown function inside eventHandlers.jsx and use this.setState.

Am I doing something wrong or may be this can be done doing another thing?

Comment: Can you share the exact message you're getting when you call the method? Can you debug the application, if so, what is being imported as "EventHandlers"? Does it have the function implementations?

Comment: Yes, it has function implementations that are used by SearchComponent and baseSearchComponent

Answer (score 0):

At line 14, you should add a comma to indicate you're going to define another property.

```
        return transportOptions;
      },
    // ^ This comma was missing!
```

It's worth noting that I would declare the `openModeDropdown` method as `openModeDropdown: function () { ...` instead of `openModeDropdown() {...` for consistency.

The `eventHandlers.jsx` should look like the following:

```
import constants from '../shared/util/constants.json';

let eventHandlers = {
  getTransportModeItems: function() {
    console.log("function triggered");
    // component.props.actions.updateNavigator('basalRate')
    const transportModes = constants.transport_modes
    let transportOptions = []
    for (var k = 0; k < transportModes.length; k++) {
        transportOptions.push(<li key={k}
        onClick={this.handleSelectMode.bind(this, transportModes[k])}>
        {transportModes[k].label} <img src={transportModes[k].icon} /></li>)
    }
    return transportOptions;
  },

  openModeDropdown: function () {
    this.setState({displayMode: !this.state.displayMode})
  }
};

export default eventHandlers;
```